# is it problem if the Voltage at home is 270v

Tags: voltage

I recently called an boiler technician, and while he was doing his think,
he noted that the electricity in my house is on 270 volts.
I think the standard for my country is 205 to 245 and this is like 10% above the maximum.

Assuming there was no error in the readings, how is this high voltage reflecting my bills,
if I use mainly electric devices:

- AC
- Boiler
- washing machine
- old fridge
- electric stove
- 2 desktop PCs
- energy saving light bulbs

Is any of this devices in danger ? For one year ago I had to replace all (normal old) light bulbs with energy saving light bulbs ... cose they burned on every 2-3 week.
Also there are constant problem with the Air Conditioning on extreme weather.

Comment: It is unclear how this value was measured, and if it isn't just appearing to be 270V on a multimeter without true rms that is measuring a very distorted sine wave. I would suggest that you contact your electricity provider about this, and I don't really know if this site is well suited for this question.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I agree with your 100% I have planed to make better measurement, and if it is confirmed I will call the Electricity Provider... but I guess they will say: "this is normal, don't worry". So I wont to collect some information on how serious this is.

Comment: Yeah, my guess would be an off-brand multimeter making an inaccurate (non-RMS) measurement. Your supply may be a little high but an accurate measurement will probably show it's within limits. Effect on your bill will be minimal (high power appliances are mostly heaters, and they'll just get the job done faster!) but I'd consider a surge suppressor for the PCs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but **EXTREMELY** unlikely that the voltage is that high.
There are reasons why it can be and may be in some cases but it would not usually be in the interests of the supply company.

If you live at the transformer end of a very long distribution line with many houses etc  and the reading was done at a low load period AND the supplier is a "cowboy" and trying to save money they MAY have set the system up so people at the far end get OK voltage during high load periods. This MAY save them money on copper lines.

BUT it is more likely that the measurement was not accurate - as others have said - spiky voltage due to industrial loads, low quality meter etc. Getting a measurement made by an independent competent person would be wise.  The supply authority may help but if they have done it on purpose their answer may not be accurate.

Voltages that high might damage many things.
Bulgarian mains is nominally 230 VAC 50 Hz and 220 - 240 VAC would be expected.
270/230 = +17 %.
For heating power rises with v^2 .
(270/230)^2 = +38%.

**IF the voltage really is high**

Heating elements resistances tend to rise with temperature so you would probably not see the full +38% but power consumption would be up. With  thermostats this would make no difference to power use but reliability may suffer.

Anything with an electric motor in may be at risk - from your list: AC, washing machine
old fridge, maybe timer in electric stove, fans in 2 desktop PCs.

Filament bulbs would be severely affected - mainly from startup surge and energy saving light bulbs may also suffer. Power supplies in PCs and other appliances also may suffer.

**Testing:**

1. Contact competent person - as above
2. Do it yourself. A basic multitester with an AC mains capable range should be accurate to 5% or better. Measure at various times of day. If you get a very high reading when not power is being used (early hours of morning. middle of afternoon in mild weather) and much lower readings during heavy load periods, be suspicious.

### SAFETY

**Note that cheap meters may have a high voltage AC range but be marginally safe or unsafe for mains AC measurement. Consult the handbook or supplier to check. Inadequately rated meters have the potential to kill you when connected to mains AC!**

Answer (score 4):

The #1 reason for measuring a voltage and getting an unexpectedly high reading is a dying battery in a handheld multimeter. The reading is a ratio to the internal reference so as the reference begins to go out of regulation the reading rises above the correct value. There is usually some kind of indication such as a battery symbol on the LCD, but it is usually fairly subtle.

Answer (score 2):

On the question of billing, Electricity meters usually measure power, so having a higher or lower voltage will generally not mean you are being charged for more or less power than you're getting.  You might, however, not want the power.  For example an incandescent light bulb will be brighter with a higher voltage, and you will have to pay for that extra brightness whether you want it or not.

The costs to your supplier are largely related to current rather than voltage an P=V*I so if you're getting a higher voltage less current will be needed per watt, and this in turn reduces losses in the supply network.

On the question of measurement it's worth remembering that the 270 volts you're talking about is an RMS value where RMS is a formula for describing a potentially complicated wave shape with a single number.  If you're getting a pure sine wave at 270V then you can infer that the peak is 381.  If, however, your supply is not a pure sine wave because of mains disturbance or some other distortion of the wave shape the peak might not be so high.  I wouldn't recommend connecting a scope to the mains to find out unless you're an expert in this kind of thing.

Have you had any problems with your supply, e.g. appliances failing, electrical equipment exploding etc?

Comment: thanks for the on point answer, about appliances problems: The heater of the boiler recently defected with no reason (it was checked 6 month ago). AC is behaving strange on extreme weather change. Filament bulbs burn in 2-3 weeks ... and we changed all of them. One of the PC has some strange power problems (seems like to low power on some components). Of course .. this is all subjective and may not be related at all... But it made me thinking.

Comment: It is very difficult to say if it is likely that there is something wrong with your supply or not.  A flat battery in a meter would not explain why light bulbs are failing very quickly.  Your supply company might be interested because what you're seeing may indicate some kind of a fault that they need to deal with anyway.  Do you know if your neighbors are having problems?  Are you very near large industrial loads?  Where do you live? In a street or in an isolated house in a remote area?